# Am I a UI designer?

Tags: interface-design

I'm familiar with making mobile apps interface, but only "images". I don't make any code, just images. And the developers need to deal with the other stuff.

Can I say that I'm a UI designer? Or to say this do I need to develop the interfaces in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UI designer is involved in the interface of an app or site. You do not need to know code, but it is recommended to know it, as it will help the design process go smoother and quicker. Some designs may look good, but not function well according to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to code to be any kind of designer, but you'll work with developers and get to know how 'the other stuff' works over time. Now, about calling yourself a designer, if you're asking that, you probably still need to work on it.